Issue with rtsp and appsrc in gstreamer. Stream with 3 second delay and VLC sais "picture is too late to be displayed"
I need to dynamically add and remove rtsp pipeline to existing gstreamer pipeline. Since gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch works with the pipeline as a whole, I decided to use appsync and appsrc.
The rtsp pipeline looks like this:

appsrc name=videosrc is-live=True format=GST_FORMAT_TIME block=True ! queue max-size-buffers=5 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 config-interval=1

The main pipeline looks like this:

tee name=videotee ! queue ! fakesink v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! imxvideoconvert_g2d ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,fps=10/1 ! videoconvert! tee name=t0 t0. ! videoconvert! queue max-size-buffers=1 ! x264enc ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,payload=127 ! videotee. t0. ! queue max-size-buffers=1 ! videoconvert! video/x-raw, format=I420 ! appsink name=vidsink max-buffers=1 drop=true

Part of the webrtc pipeline is dynamically connected to vedeotee.
To set the timestamp, I use the following approach:
ctx->timestamp = 0

...

GST_BUFFER_PTS (buffer) = ctx->timestamp;
GST_BUFFER_DTS (buffer) = ctx->timestamp;
ctx->timestamp += GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer);

That is, I use the duration from the original frame and add it to the timestamp that will be used for the next frame.
There are regular frame drops in the main pipeline. Perhaps this is what causes the error in vlc.
At the same time, the video stream is stable and without delay in the webrtc stream. In rtsp, I see a delay of about 3 seconds. Also, vlc periodically stops and buffers the video. Seconds in the vlc timeline go 3 times slower.
I understand that the problem is with the buffer timestamp, after appsrc. But I don't understand how to set this time correctly.
